# What are the % Odds?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, odds

NEED SOMEONE GOOD IN MATH! 
My father, my brother & myself all have AB- Blood Type. According to The Stanford School of Medicine Blood Center around 0.6% of the population has the ABneg blood type. So my question is: 
What are the odds (%) that 3 people directly related (like us: father, son, daughter) would have AB- Blood?
Thank you

Comment: Blood type is inherited: https://www.bswhealth.com/patient-tools/blood-center/Pages/blood-type-genetics-and-compatibility.aspx.

Comment: The odds is not measured in percentages

Comment: This isn't a question that can be answered from the information given: you have to look up the data.  The question itself is ambiguous, because the answer depends on what else you know; for instance, the answer depends on the blood types of the mother(s) of the son and daughter.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two reasons why this question can't be answered:

1. Blood type is inherited. To do the calculations that you seem to want, you would have to either assume that blood type among family members was independent (but it isn't) or else know the details of how it is inherited and then know the blood types of the other people in your family.
2. Even if you were looking at something that *was* independent (like, say, "all our social security numbers are exactly divisible by 7!" you haven't given us enough info because we don't know who else is in your "directly related" group.  The answer would be very different, depending on family size.